# Comma before ᴀɴᴅ after "on average"?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases, style-manuals

I need your help on how best to write this sentence:

> The results show that the developed methods(,) on average(,) lead to 10% less costs.

Do I need the commas before **and** after *on average*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As broad guidance, the normal place for a prepositional modifier is {S + V [+ O] + modifier} and this construction does not require a comma.

“…  that the developed methods lead to 10% less costs on average.”

Other positions may be correctly adopted for emphasis, but these all do require commas:

“…  that, **on average**, the developed methods lead to 10% less costs.”

“…  that the developed methods, **on average**, lead to 10% less costs.”

“…  that the developed methods lead, **on average**, to 10% less costs.”

“…  that the developed methods lead to 10%, **on average**, less costs.”

PS I would use **lower costs** rather than “**less costs**”

Comment: Thanks Greybeard for your answer. Can I use 'less costs' instead of 'lower costs' or is 'less costs' a mistake?

Comment: "Less costs" is not idiomatic - it sounds awkward - it would make the reader stumble. There are several ways of expressing the idea but "less costs" is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks Greybeard for your answer. What about "less surplus energy" or "In periods with less PV generation"? Would you also use 'lower' in these examples?

Comment: You must realise that English is heavily dependent upon context. There is no point in giving short phrases as examples as it is impossible to respond accurately. I think that you might need to add more new questions.

Comment: Okay thanks. Then I am going to add more questions. But thanks for the answer to the original question with the commas (I accepted it)